# mount via cli problem and comparison with nautilus connect to server SAMBA share

Tags: networking, mount, samba, network-drive

I would like to know the difference when mounting the network drive via `mount`, i.e. below and via nautilus -> connect to server.

```
sudo mount -o user=<USER>,domain=<DOMAIN>,password=<PASS> <server> <mountpoint>
```

The reason is that, everytime I use `sudo mount`, I got `mount error(13): Permission denied`. On `dmesg`

```
[484014.284261] CIFS: Attempting to mount <network_drive_address>
[484015.107961] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

However, using nautilus connect to server I have no problem mounting the drive, so they clearly used different approaches in doing this. With the `mount`, I've also tried using the `sec=ntlm` and with and without `vers=1.0` (to try version 1 and later than 1) options as some suggested and still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to use `username` rather than `user` when supplying credentials ... 

Comment: @matigo just tried that, still the same. Any idea what might went wrong? Anyway, based on the output both `username` and `user` are parsed to `user` in the end so it didn't change anything technically.

Comment: What is hosting the Samba share? Is the host Ubuntu, MacOS, Windows, or something else? Depending on the host, you may need to be incredibly specific with the `mount` statement …

Comment: @matigo is there any way to check that? I am unsure about the host since this is my university's

Comment: Did you also check the uppercas / lowercase in your command?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen Yes. Pretty sure it was fine (I tried multiple times). Better yet, I've copy-paste the password from my password manager. Also, if it was wrong username/password, I would not be able to mount via nautilus/GUI.

Comment: Could you try with the option `-v` (verbose) to get more details?